# How to change the color of single point in spiderweb chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to change the color of a single point where its value is lower than 60%.

(For example, turn the blue color of two points which are in the pink area into a red color.)

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Javascript:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'line'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Budget vs spending',
    x: -80
  },

  pane: {
    size: '80%'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support',
      'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0
  },

  yAxis: {
     gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
     lineWidth: 0,
     min: 0,
     max: 100
  },

  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
  },

  legend: {
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 70,
    layout: 'vertical'
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Allocated Budget',
    color: 'blue',
    pointPlacement: 'on',
    data: [83, 79, 40, 35, 97, 80],
    pointPlacement:'on',

  }, {
    name: 'lower than 60%',
    data: [60,60,60,60,60,60],
    pointPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 2,
    type: 'area',
    color: '#ffbce6',
    dashStyle: 'shortdash',
  }]

});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tk859qje/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options is to change the data for your `Allocated Budget` series to this:

`data: [83, 79, {y:40, color:'red'}, {y:35, color:'red'}, 97, 80]`

Check the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mpof48nu/

Comment: thank you! but is that possible to do it with a function to change the color dynamically? If the data value changes, the color changes automatically.

Comment: You can change the way you feed data to highcharts. You can do something like `data: dataVaraiable` and build dataVariable from your backend. I hope this makes sense.